# Can I use concatenation, repetition, or `define with $readmemb or $readmemh?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm implementing a single cycle MIPS processor and initializing my memory using `$readmemb` or `$readmemh`. That being the case I want to initialize my register file with some 32-bit instructions, but I don't want to have to write those instructions out by hand.

Could I feed a scheme like the one below into `$readmemh` and have it initialize my memory to those values? What are my limitations with these `$readmemh` and `$readmemb`?

```
`define ADD 5'b0xx01
{1'b1, 5'd0, 5'd0, 5'd0, `ADD, 11'd1}
{1'b1, 5'd0, 5'd0, 5'd0, `ADD, 11'd7}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use concatenation, repetition or `` `define `` macros inside files passed to `$readmemb` or `$readmemh`.  The syntax for those files is described in the IEEE Std 1800-2012, section "21.4 Loading memory array data from a file".  The syntax is pretty limited.  Values are separated by whitespace only, may contain optional underscores for readability, and comments are allowed (`/**/` or `//`).

Possible alternatives include:

- Use a script (such as Perl) to generate the readmem files outside of Verilog.
- Use the concatenation, repetition and define syntax you've shown in Verilog in for loops.